# Можно в IntelliJ IDEA посмотреть где используется метод?

Tags: intellij-idea

И если можно, то как? Поиск(Ctrl+F и т.п.) не подходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для просмотра того где используется метод нужно сделать следующее:

1. Установить курсор на название метода который хотите проверить
2. Нажать сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> или зажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> и нажать <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd> на имя метода.

После этого либо произойдет переход к месту использования или появится список мест где используется данный метод.
Данная комбинация так же может работать с классами и интерфейсами.

Comment: Обычно достаточно просто cntrl

Comment: @Kostya M да такой способ тоже есть, забыл про него.

Answer (score 4):

Существует второй вариант. Можно навести курсор мыши на название метода и зажать клавишу CNTRL. В таком случае название метода начнет подчеркиваться и на него просто следует нажать.